# Unable to install extensions on gnome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I wish to install some extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/. So here is a history of what I did. I install [ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Successfully done.
Now I installed gnome on it using the commands-

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
$ sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Last command just to ensure that it is installed (usually it is installed by default). I chose gdb3 on prompt while running the second command.
Here are the info. with respect to the versions-

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.18.5
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 57.0
```

Later on, I installed the firefox gnome-shell integration [plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome) from the firefox addons manager.

Even after logging out and rebooting, I am getting the following messages on firefox (my primary browser) and chrome respectively-

Firefox message:

[image]

Chrome message:

[image]

As a result, I can't install extensions from the site. Ask if any more info is needed. Please help!

Comment: Did you select GNOME session instead of Unity at the login screen?

Comment: I did not get any option like that, but the login screen was not unity.

Comment: It was of gnome.

Comment: Output of `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`?

Comment: `ubuntu`. Now it looks like gnome-session is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have logged in to a Unity session instead of a GNOME session.

If you're using GDM3, there should be a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the "sign in" button at the login screen. Click on it and select GNOME instead of Unity.